# Using Curl in Php to get Json STD Class Object Data

Tags: php, json, curl

I use the curl code below to get and display json file contents and everything works fine with the code below

when I print the json result with

```
$json = json_decode($response);
 print_r($json);
```

Am having the result displayed in this format

```
stdClass Object ( [id] => 123
[food] => Array ( [0] => rice ) 

[buyer] => AkwaezeOby 

[amount] => 2000 )
```

Now am trying to get values for food and buyer only and I have tried  this below but cannot get it to work

```
print_r($json["food"][0]);
print_r($json["buyer"]);

or

echo $json["food"][0];
echo $json["buyer"];
```

Below is the working code for data display. can someone help me to get values for **food** and **buyer** only. thanks

```
$curl = curl_init();

curl_setopt_array($curl, array( 
CURLOPT_URL => "myapi.com", 
CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true, 
CURLOPT_ENCODING => "", 
CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10, 
CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 30, 
CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1, 
CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "GET", 
//CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => "$data", 
CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array( 
"accept: application/json", 
"authorization: --my number goes here--", 
"content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8" 
), 
));

$response = curl_exec($curl); 
$err = curl_error($curl);

curl_close($curl);


 $json = json_decode($response);

print_r($json);
```

Comment: Can you please paste the raw json from ```$response```? It'll help us answer the question. (```print_r($response)```) Thanks.

Comment: stdClass Object ( [id] => 123
[food] => Array ( [0] => rice ) 

[buyer] => AkwaezeOby 

[amount] => 2000 )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

a possible solution could be using this

```
$json = json_decode($response, true);
```

From [Docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) the second parameter: When TRUE, returned objects will be converted into associative arrays.